# Unity: 3D screen resolution android

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, resolution, stretch

So far I have only encountered tutorials and stackoverflow answers that address 2D and UI issues. Mine is a bit different I feel because it pertains to 3D games. I have a 3D game that I try to build on android using Unity remote, but for some reason it comes out being stretched out on my phone. How do I go about addressing this? Does it have to do with the camera?? Does the Fit All Screen Size asset resolve this (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22132) or is it only for 2D things? Thanks for your time! :)

Screen shot from Unity Remote via mobile phone. You can see how it's quite stretched out here:

[image: Screen shot from Unity Remote via mobile phone. You can see how it's quite stretched out here]

Comment: You don't need plugin for this Canvas Scaler should do that for you. See the video linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805502/automatically-resize-ui-size-on-different-screen-resolution/36805537?s=1|55.0383#36805537) answer.

Comment: Ah I saw the video but it didn't address what I was referring to. Apologies if I don't know the terminology to describe this problem. But I have added a picture to my question.